# SharePoint Designer Custom Workflow

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-designer

I am creating a custom workflow in SP Designer 2013. I have a form that when submitted the workflow status goes to submitted. When a owner of the site goes in to edit the form or review it the workflow status should change to reviewed. If the owner goes in to the form and approves or denies it the status should change accordingly. All I am getting is the submitted status. Here is what I have: 
Step 1:
If Continuous Improvement Ideas: Admin Approval is empty
set workflow status to submitted
else if continuous improvement ideas: admin approval equals denied
set workflow status to closed
else set workflow status to approved

Comment: so whats the problem?

Comment: When I go in to edit the form to approve or deny the workflow never moves past submitted. Sorry I guess I forgot to say what my issue was

Comment: Okay kind of an update. When I submit the original form the workflow status stays on submitted even when I go back in to the form and change the admin approval. If the original form that was submitted was stated that the admin approval was approved or denied then the workflow status will change...... so how do I get the workflow status to change if the form has been modified?